# Statistical test using Gmean to compare multiple algorithms on multiple datasets

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, multiclass-classification

I am new in this area. I am facing some issues while comparing the algorithms using statistical test. I have following result of Gmean of some classification algorithm. Abalone, Balance-scale, Car, Chess are the datasets here and ROS, RUS, RFS, NoS are the algorithms.

If I want to compare which dataset is better than others using some statistical test like, t-test, Friedmen test, Wilcoxon test etc then is it possible that I can compare the algorithm using the following table?

```
                  ROS       RUS     RFS     NoS
Abalone           0.003     0.0036  0.0039  0
Balance-scale     0.8858    0.8065  0.8966  0.9417
Car               0.9191    0.7216  0.9056  0.9094
Chess             0.4912    0.1973  0.5084  0.1438
```

If anyone has any idea about it please help me. Or you can share any references from where I can find the solutions. I studied these statistical test, null hypothesis, p-value etc but couldn't understand whether it is possible or not to compare these algorithms using Gmean.

***G-mean = Geometric Mean, used to evaluate the performance of multiclass classifiers

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of machine learning algorithms is not commonly evaluated with null hypothesis significance testing (NHST).

Machine learning performance is typically evaluated by performance on a hold-out data (e.g., validation or test), regardless of the evaluation metric.